# wxPython wx.StaticBitmap colour 240,240,240

Tags: python, wxpython

when I create a wx.Staticbitmap and put in Bitmap in it, it seems to display a colour with RBG = 240, 240, 240 as transparent (which should be a light grey).
To work around this, I set the background colour of the wx.Staticbitmap also to 240,240,240.

Code looks like:

```
     self.image_container = wx.StaticBitmap(parent, id=-1, size=(self.x, self.y), pos=(0,0))
     self.image_container.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(240, 240, 240))

     self.image_container.SetBitmap(bmp)

     self.image_container.Update()
     self.image_container.Refresh()
```

The Bitmap has a depth of 24 Bits. May I got the style of the wx.StaticBitmap wrong or something but i couldn't figure it out. It seems like it is a bug.

Python version is: 2.7.13

Wx version is: wxPython==4.0.0b2

Runs on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old feature of the Windows API from back when commonly used image formats did not support transparency. The intent was to provide a way for things like toolbar and menu icons to have transparent areas and by default they used the light gray color to indicate where the transparent areas should be, because that was the default window background color back then.

Other workarounds are possible. The image could be tweaked in memory before it is given to the staticbitmap, but it would probably be easiest to just fix it in the image file itself.  For example, you can edit the image files and change the 240 gray pixels to 241 or something. Or you can convert the image file to a different format that does support transparency, which should bypass the automatic transparency setting.